# How to rewrite User.companies to return User.companies.where(status:"active").all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I recently switched to soft deletion of some company objects and want to replace `User.companies` to return `User.companies.where(status: "active")`.

Here is my User relationship:

```
 has_many :companies, :through =>  :collaborations
```

Is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out:

```
has_many :companies, :through =>  :collaborations, :conditions => {status: "active"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to override `User.companies` is to use [default_scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class).

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(status: "active")
end
```

However I recommend to read http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil before using `default_scope`.